Using GEE models without clustered data
I am studying a set of longitudinal data with an N-of-1 approach. This means studying each patient in the data separately. I know there is correlation in my response variable and I am looking to use GEE models to select a specific correlation structure via the QIC. However, in separating the data for different patients I have then surely removed the multilevel structure in my dataset? I am using the geeglm() function and specify a separate id variable for every measurement for the independence correlation structure and it seems to work fine, giving the same estimates as the linear model. The "ar1" correlation structure doesn't appear to work in the same way and specifying the id variable to be the same value for all observations makes sense for my data but the standard error and p-values are very small while the estimates and phi estimate are close to other models I have used (GLS). I have researched into using jackknife estimates instead but this results in the standard error of the coefficients to be 0. Is there another way to use the "ar1" structure of GEEs in this N-of-1 setting?
